# Xrm.Navigation.openForm set lookup field automatically from the previous form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, powerapps, xrm

I added a new button inside my "Parcours" form that takes me to another form "Question" with a `Xrm.Navigation.openForm`

[image]

The "Question" form has a lookup field from "Parcours" that I want to populate set automatically from the previous form like this for example :

[image]

This is my code for my button, I want to detect the ID of the parcours automatically and set it in the new "Question" form

```
function NavigateQuestion(){
    var entityFormOptions = {};
entityFormOptions["entityName"] = "zs_question";
var formParameters = {};

// Set lookup column
formParameters["zs_parcours"] = ""; // I want to put the ID here from the previous form.
formParameters["zs_parcoursname"] = ""; // Name of the parcours.
formParameters["zs_parcourstype"] = "zs_parcours"; // Table name. 

Xrm.Navigation.openForm(entityFormOptions, formParameters).then(
    function (success) {
        console.log(success);
        console.log(formParameters);
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the values and assign from the current record form itself.

Make sure to pass the formContext for latest client API methods (I put the syntax in commented code section).

```
// Set lookup column
formParameters["zs_parcours"] = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId(); // or by using form context -- formContext.data.entity.getId();
formParameters["zs_parcoursname"] = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("zs_name").getValue(); // or by using form context -- formContext.getAttribute("zs_name").getValue();
formParameters["zs_parcourstype"] = "zs_parcours";
```